# Ellipse find equation and eccentricity

Tags: coordinate-systems, elliptic-equations

A set of lines $x+y-2 +A(2x+y-3)=0$ represent incident rays on an ellipse $s = 0$ and $2x+3y-23+B(2x+y-3)=0$ represents the set of reflective rays from the ellipse where $A,B \in \Bbb R$.

If $p( 3, 7 )$ is a point on the ellipse normal at which meets the major Axis at $N$, find eccentricity of the ellipse.

I am unable to even proceed please give small help

Comment: This is very hard to decipher. In particular, what is $N$? It seems like it should be coordinates of a point, but it looks like just a number. Perhaps there’s a translation issue. However, you might find [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#The_normal_bisects_the_angle_between_the_lines_to_the_foci) of ellipses helpful.

Comment: Yes N is a point coordinate

Comment: Not getting plz help

Answer (score 1):

The first set of lines are all passing through $(1,1)$ while the second set passes through $\left(-\dfrac{7}{2}, 10\right)$. By the [Reflective Property of Ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#:%7E:text=Focus%2Dto%2Dfocus%20reflection%20property%5Bedit%5D,pass%20through%20the%20other%20focus.)

we can see that the above points are the two focii, $S,S'$ of the ellipse.

To find length of major axis use $2a= SP+S'P$ with $P(3,7)$. Then use that $SS'=2ae$ where $e$ is the required eccentricity.